# FadeOut pseudo element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I have a home page with images and `.png` texture which is a pseudo element over each image. I would need this `.png` texture to `FadeOut` on hover. Having it configured in the way it is, how may I implement the feature? Or would it be easier to make it by changing the current set up?

```css
@import url('http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css');

/*HEADER*/
#logo {
    margin-top: 12px;
}

/*BODY*/
body {
    background-color: #262626;
    padding: 70px 0 70px 0;
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .container{
        max-width: 1080px;
    }
}
.row > div > a > img {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
.top-buffer {
    margin-top: 25px;
}

/*IMG OVERLAY*/
.img-container a {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
.img-container a:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: url('http://feanor.cz/public/img/web/img-cover.png');
}
/*.img-container a:hover:before {
    display: none;
}*/

/*DROPDOWN*/
ul.nav li.dropdown:hover > ul.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
    background-color: #1e1e1e;
}
.navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu > li > a {
    color: #aaa;
}
.navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #161616;
}

/*IMAGES*/
.masonry-container {
    padding: 0;
}
.item {
    padding: 3px;
}
.item img {
    max-width: 100%;
}

/*CONTACTS*/
.contact_photo img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
.contact {
    color: #aaa;
}
.contact a {
    color: #aaa;
}
.contact a:hover {
    color: #fff;
}
.contact img {
    margin-top: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.contact p {
    font-size: 12pt;
}

/*FOOTER*/
#footer-bottom {
    min-height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    color: #777;
}
#footer-bottom > li > i {
    margin-left: -5px;
}
.copyright {
    padding-top: 15px;
}
#email_footer {
    padding-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top container-fluid">
    <div class="container">
      <a href="http://feanor.cz/">
        <img class="navbar-left" id="logo" src="http://feanor.cz/public/img/web/logo_studio.gif" width="200" alt="Feanor Studio">
      </a>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>
          <a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sx-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 top-buffer img-container">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="http://feanor.cz/public/img/painting/oil/8t.jpg">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sx-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 top-buffer img-container">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="http://feanor.cz/public/img/photo/portrait/32t.jpg">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sx-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 top-buffer img-container">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="http://feanor.cz/public/img/photo/wedding/26t.jpg">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sx-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 top-buffer img-container">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="http://feanor.cz/public/img/photo/car/5t.jpg">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sx-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 top-buffer img-container">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="http://feanor.cz/public/img/photo/product/10t.jpg">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sx-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 top-buffer img-container">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="http://feanor.cz/public/img/photo/interior/4t.jpg">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="footer-bottom navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom container-fluid">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="copyright navbar-left">
          © 2016, Feanor, All rights reserved
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right navbar-right">
          <li>
            <a target="_blank" href="#">
              <i class="fa fa-instagram fa-2x faicon"></i>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a target="_blank" href="#">
              <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-2x faicon"></i>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p>lybvit@gmail.com</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Pseudo Elements (``::after``, ``::before``) are a CSS thing, they aren't part of the DOM to be manipulated solely by JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the hover pseudo selector and target the :before pseudoselector use opacity to toggle between the states and transition to animate it

```
.img-container:hover a:before {
        content: "";
        opacity:0;
      -webkit-transition: all 1s; /* Safari */
        transition: all 1s;
    }
```

```css
@import url('http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css');

/*HEADER*/
#logo {
    margin-top: 12px;
}

/*BODY*/
body {
    background-color: #262626;
    padding: 70px 0 70px 0;
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .container{
        max-width: 1080px;
    }
}
.row > div > a > img {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
.top-buffer {
    margin-top: 25px;
}

/*IMG OVERLAY*/
.img-container a {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
.img-container a:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    opacity:1;
    background: url('http://feanor.cz/public/img/web/img-cover.png');
}
.img-container:hover a:before {
    content: "";
    opacity:0;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s; /* Safari */
    transition: all 1s;
}
/*.img-container a:hover:before {
    display: none;
}*/

/*DROPDOWN*/
ul.nav li.dropdown:hover > ul.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
    background-color: #1e1e1e;
}
.navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu > li > a {
    color: #aaa;
}
.navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #161616;
}

/*IMAGES*/
.masonry-container {
    padding: 0;
}
.item {
    padding: 3px;
}
.item img {
    max-width: 100%;
}

/*CONTACTS*/
.contact_photo img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
.contact {
    color: #aaa;
}
.contact a {
    color: #aaa;
}
.contact a:hover {
    color: #fff;
}
.contact img {
    margin-top: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.contact p {
    font-size: 12pt;
}

/*FOOTER*/
#footer-bottom {
    min-height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    color: #777;
}
#footer-bottom > li > i {
    margin-left: -5px;
}
.copyright {
    padding-top: 15px;
}
#email_footer {
    padding-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top container-fluid">
    <div class="container">
      <a href="http://feanor.cz/">
        <img class="navbar-left" id="logo" src="http://feanor.cz/public/img/web/logo_studio.gif" width="200" alt="Feanor Studio">
      </a>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>
          <a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sx-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 top-buffer img-container">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="http://feanor.cz/public/img/painting/oil/8t.jpg">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sx-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 top-buffer img-container">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="http://feanor.cz/public/img/photo/portrait/32t.jpg">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sx-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 top-buffer img-container">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="http://feanor.cz/public/img/photo/wedding/26t.jpg">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sx-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 top-buffer img-container">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="http://feanor.cz/public/img/photo/car/5t.jpg">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sx-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 top-buffer img-container">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="http://feanor.cz/public/img/photo/product/10t.jpg">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sx-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 top-buffer img-container">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="http://feanor.cz/public/img/photo/interior/4t.jpg">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="footer-bottom navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom container-fluid">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="copyright navbar-left">
          © 2016, Feanor, All rights reserved
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right navbar-right">
          <li>
            <a target="_blank" href="#">
              <i class="fa fa-instagram fa-2x faicon"></i>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a target="_blank" href="#">
              <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-2x faicon"></i>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p>lybvit@gmail.com</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'd need it to have a `FadeOut` effect

Answer (score 2):

Use :hover psuedo class and transitions to fade out the image:

```
.img-container:hover a:before {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s ease;
}
```

This will fade from default `opacity: 1;` to 0 over one second with an easing animation effect.